# Toggleable nconf-like menu from command output

Tags: bash, menu

I'm trying to create the following kind of nconf-like `space`-toggleable menu:

```
[*] 1st item
[*] 2nd one
[ ] 3rd one
[*] 4th one
```

The items should be created according to the output of the command in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `dialog` (or `whiptail`; they are very similar) with the `--checklist` widget.

Here's an example command:

```
options=$(
  dialog 2>&1 1>/dev/tty \
         --keep-tite \
         --checklist "Dialog title" 20 120 4 \
         tag1 "1st item" on \
         tag2 "2nd item" off \
         tag3 "3rd item" off \
         tag4 "4th item" on
)
```

The end result is that `$options` will contain the list of tag values for the selected items. Taking that command apart:

`dialog` uses stdout to write to the terminal and then writes its own output (the list of selected tags) to stderr. That's a bit awkward for scripting; the `$(...)` construct redirects `stdout` to a pipe which `bash` can read from. So we duplicate the pipe `stdout` to `stderr` (`2>&1`) so that the final output will be captured, and then set `stdout` back to the terminal (`2>/dev/tty`)

```
  dialog 2>&1 1>/dev/tty \
```

`--keep-tite` is dialog-specific; it causes dialog to use the "alternate screen", which effectively means that once the widget is finished, the display will be restored. Try it with and without if that wasn't clear.

```
         --keep-tite \
```

The first four arguments after `--checklist` are the windows's title, height and width, and the menu height (which will normally be the same as the number of items)

```
         --checklist "Dialog title" 20 120 4 \
```

The rest of the arguments are in sets of three: a tag (which should not have whitespace or shell metacharacters) which will be used to identify the selected options; the actual text to be displayed; and an indication of whether the option is initially selected or not.

```
         tag1 "1st item" on \
         tag2 "2nd item" off \
         tag3 "3rd item" off \
         tag4 "4th item" on
```